# How can make an noUiSlider to show me many numbers of sliders on a foreach?

Tags: arrays, foreach

I Have this noUiSlider, it works fine! But if is working on {foreach} then working only the one slider of the foreach. How can I set it up so that it working on foreach? This is an example work.

```
{foreach from=$v.my_elements_array item=v}


<div class="form-group">
   <div id="slider_id"></div>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input id="input_start" type="text" class="form-control" name="from">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
         To
        </span>
        <input id="input_end" type="text" class="form-control" name="to">
      </div>
</div>

{/foreach}
```

After this is show me  only the last slider of 4 i have like: (slider_2, slider_3, slider_4 ).

```
This is my script and is working perfect for any numbers of sliders but not in array.

var UINoUiSliders = function () {

    return {
        //main function to initiate the module
        init: function () {

            // slider
            $('#slider_id').noUiSlider({
                     range: [0,1000]
                    ,start: [300,700]
                    ,handles: 2
                    ,connect: true
                    ,step: 1
                    ,serialization: {
                         to: [$('#input_start'), $('#input_end')]
                        ,resolution: 1
                }
            });
         }
     };
 }();
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and simple Answer, you have to use classes over IDs:

```
$('div.js_slider').noUiSlider();
```

Maby some kind of clever lookup for your related inputs too.

Comment: I am sorry! Where need to pu that?

Comment: Found this using google: https://gist.github.com/leongersen/7560025 && http://jsfiddle.net/Yc4Q7/